# Best way to find out if user is already registered

Tags: java, database, spring

How to find out, that a user is already registered, for e.g. in a web application? Like I have a database of 1 million users. Every time comparing every single row in database is inefficient. Is there any other optimal approach?

Comment: yes, and might be he registers with different name, or ip, or username ! obvious comparisons would be the username only, checking if it exists !

Answer (score 8):

> *Every time comparing every single row in database is inefficient*

I gather that you're hauling the entire DB table contents into Java's memory by a `SELECT * FROM User` and then looping over every row in a `while` loop and comparing its username by `equals()` like below, is that true?

```
public boolean exists(String username) throws SQLException {
    // ... Declare, etc.

    statement = connection.prepareStatement("SELECT * FROM User");
    resultSet = statement.executeQuery();
    while (resultSet.next()) {
        if (username.equals(resultSet.getString("username"))) {
            return true;
        }
    }
    return false;

    // ... Close, etc (in finally!)
}
```

Then that's indeed very inefficient. You should be indexing the username column (it probably already is, with `UNIQUE` constraint) and then make use of SQL `WHERE` clause. It'll return exactly zero or one rows and the DB will do its very best finding it, which is usually much, much faster than the above Java approach.

```
public boolean exists(String username) throws SQLException {
    // ... Declare, etc.

    statement = connection.prepareStatement("SELECT id FROM User WHERE username = ?");
    statement.setString(1, username);
    resultSet = statement.executeQuery();
    return resultSet.next();

    // ... Close, etc (in finally!)
}
```

In a nutshell, as long as you make proper use of DB indexes and write SQL queries as such that it returns **exactly** the information you need, without any necessity for filtering using Java or additional queries afterwards, then it'll be most efficient approach.

Comment: and don't forget to place an index on the USERNAME column of the USER table for increased search performance!

Comment: You might just use `SELECT count(*) …` instead, in my opinion it reads clearer since you are not really interested in getting the ID anyway.

Answer (score 1):

You can optimize your `query`.You can maintain a unique username(or your unique parameter) for user and when someone trying to register,You can pass that `usename` to query and check it is already registered or not

Comment: yes, and as names, or ip, can be same ! obvious comparisons would be on the username or email only, checking if it exists, so each row has to be queried !

Comment: @RachitMishra you can see  the second example of Balusc,That's what exactly I said.Passing the username and checking weather  the records are available or not.